# Matlab libsvm - having troubles with the vector coefficients w

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

My data matrix is a 1000x65K matrix that contains 500 positive examples and 500 negative examples. My features are binary (0 or 1). My labels are [ones(500,1); -ones(500,1)];

I'm training a linear svm using the following code:

```
ost = 0.1;
epsilon = 2;
gamma = 0.1;
degree = 3;
coef0 = 0;

options_string = ['-s 0 -t 0 ' ' -c ' num2str(cost) ' -p ' num2str(epsilon) ' -g ' num2str(gamma) ' -d ' num2str(degree) ' -r ' num2str(coef0) ' -b 1'];
SVRModel = svm_train(data, labels , options_string);
```

I'm calculating the coefficients vector w using the following code:

```
w = zeros(1,M);
for i=1:length(SVRModel.sv_coef)
    w = w + SVRModel.sv_coef(i)*SVRModel.SVs(i,:);
end
```

However, all the values of the resulting vector w are the same. Also, I'm getting 484 support vectors and all the first 424 svm coefficients are 0.1 and the rest of them (also 424) are -0.1.

How can that be? Can someone please shed some light on my problem?

Thanks,

Gil.

Comment: I guess you want `w(i) = w(i) + SVRModel.sv_coef(i)*SVRModel.SVs(i,:); `. Also note that using `i` as an index in MATLAB is not recommended, as it can be confused with the built-in imaginary unit `i = sqrt(-1)`. This can sometimes cause some strange bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need `gamma` and `coef0` in linear SVM.

Secondly, I think it should be

`SVRModel = svm_train(labels, data, options_string);`

in your training process.

And you can vectorize the weight and bias terms.

```
w = model.SVs' * model.sv_coef;
b = -model.rho;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply(+1). I was told that the highest the W(i) value is, the more important is the i'th feature for classification. Is that true?

Comment: Thank you GilLevi. I cannot answer this question for general cases, since there are many feature selection methods applied to determine the importance of each attribute (you can do a literature search on 'SVM feature selection'), I'm not sure whether the feature rank from those methods is consistent with the sorting of actual weights you obtained from SVM. However, if you use L1 norm penalty on the weight vector, it does automatic feature selection, so the weights corresponding to irrelevant attributes are automatically set to zero.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @lennon310. Can you please explain what do you mean by L1 norm penalty? Thanks!

Comment: GilLevi, this paper might help: http://dspace.cc.tut.fi/dpub/bitstream/handle/123456789/7993/kujala_a_walk_from_2-norm_svm.pdf?sequence=1  The |w| term in formula (1) can be |w|^2 (L2 Norm) or sum|wi| (L1 norm). I think libsvm did L2-norm optimization.